# Redirect to new page after PHP validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am very new to php and have been working on a website which contains a form for a restaurant reservation. Currently, I have one file, which contains both html and php code. The form is validated once the user clicks submit, however I was wondering how it might be possible to redirect the user to a new page, confirming their reservation, if all of the information they have entered into the form is correct.

Basically this is the process I wish the website to perform:

```
user fills out form

if validation not complete

   display error messages, loop back to form so user can correct fields

if form is validated fully

    Send user to confirmation page
```

Here is the necessary code for my reservations page:

```
....


<?php
$nameErr = $teleErr = $emailErr = $partyErr = $vipErr = $reservationErr = $timeErr = "";
$name = $tele = $email = $party = $vip = $reservation = $time = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Please enter a full name";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Invalid name entered";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["tele"])) {
        $teleErr = "Please enter a telephone number";
    } else {
        $tele = test_input($_POST["tele"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]{7,}$/",$tele)) {
            $teleErr = "Invalid telephone number entered";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Please enter an email address";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email entered";
        }
    }

    if($_POST['party']=="") {
        $partyErr = "Please select the party size";
    } else {
        $party = test_input($_POST["party"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["vip"])) {
        $vipErr = "Please make a VIP area selection";
    } else {
        $vip = test_input($_POST["vip"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["reservation"])) {
        $reservationErr = "Please enter the reservation date";
    } else {
        $reservation = test_input($_POST["reservation"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/",$reservation)) {
            $reservationErr = "Invalid reservation date";
        }
    }

    if($_POST['time']=="") {
        $timeErr = "Please select the reservation time";
    } else {
        $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>

<body>

<div id= "container">

<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<img src="Steakhouselogo.png" width="440" height="152" alt="This is an image of the Steakhouse® logo">
</div>
<br>
<p class="slogan"> <strong> Welcome to Steakhouse®, the number 1 restaurant for flame grilled goodness. </strong> </p>
</div>
<div id="links">
<ul class="nav">

</ul>
</div>
<br>

<!-- Introduction of HTML form -->
<div id="body">
<h1> Book a Table </h1>
<br><br>

<br>
<div class="view">
<img src="view.png" width="451" height="227" alt="A view of our restaurant">
</div>
<br>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<!-- Personal information -->
<div class="form">
<div class="indicates">
<br>
* indicates a required field
</div>
<p  class="ex">
<br><br>
<strong> Full Name* : </strong> <br> <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br><br>

<strong> Contact Telephone* : </strong> <br> <input type="text" placeholder="Telephone Number" name="tele" value="<?php echo $tele;?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $teleErr;?></span>
<br><br><br>

<strong> Contact Email* : </strong> <br> <input type="text" placeholder="Example@email.com" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br><br>

<!-- Party requirments -->

<br>
<strong>Select Party Size* :</strong>
<br>
<select name="party" id="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="5") echo "selected";?> value="5">1 Person (+£5)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="10") echo "selected";?> value="10">2 People (+£10)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="15") echo "selected";?> value="15">3 People (+£15)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="20") echo "selected";?> value="20">4 People (+£20)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="25") echo "selected";?> value="25">5 People (+£25)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="30") echo "selected";?> value="30">6 People (+£30)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="35") echo "selected";?> value="35">7 People (+£35)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="40") echo "selected";?> value="40">8 People (+£40)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="45") echo "selected";?> value="45">9 People (+£45)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="50") echo "selected";?> value="50">10+ People (+£50)</option>
</select>
<span id="party" class="error"><?php echo $partyErr;?></span>
<br><br><br>
<strong>Dietary Requirements:</strong>
<br><br>
Vegetarian <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Vegetarian">
<br><br>
Vegan <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Vegan">
<br><br>
Peanut Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Peanut Allergy">
<br><br>
Gluten Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Gluten Allergy">
<br><br><br>

<strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br>
Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes">
<br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br>
No <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No">
<br><br><br>

<strong> Reservation Date* : </strong> <br> <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" name="reservation" value="<?php echo $reservation;?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $reservationErr;?></span>
<br><br><br>

<strong> Reservation Time* : </strong>
<br>
<select name="time" value="<?php echo $time;?>">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="17:00") echo "selected";?> value="17:00">17:00</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="17:30") echo "selected";?> value="17:30">17:30</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="18:00") echo "selected";?> value="18:00">18:00</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="18:30") echo "selected";?> value="18:30">18:30</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="19:00") echo "selected";?> value="19:00">19:00</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="19:30") echo "selected";?> value="19:30">19:30</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="20:00") echo "selected";?> value="20:00">20:00</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="20:30") echo "selected";?> value="20:30">20:30</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="21:00") echo "selected";?> value="21:00">21:00</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="21:30") echo "selected";?> value="21:30">21:30</option>
<option <?php if (isset($time) && $time=="22:00") echo "selected";?> value="22:00">22:00</option>
</select>
<span id="time" class="error"><?php echo $timeErr;?></span>
<br><br><br>
<strong> Any Additional Information: </strong>
<br>
<textarea name="comments" placeholder="Birthdays, Class Parties..." rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>
<br><br>
<div class="totalPrice">
The total reservation price will be calculated automatically once submitted.
<br><br><br>
</div>
<div class="submitEtc">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset form">
<br><br><br><br>
....
```

I have put a lot of effort into my work thus far, so any suggestions are welcomed. Please remember I am new to web languages also. Thank you.

Comment: Usually you redirect with a simple `header('Location:someotherpage.php');` if you need any data between the page use sessions.

Comment: @Mihai, thanks for your reply friend, I realise this is a way to redirect however I am unaware of how to implement this or the sessions function. Could you please show me an example as I am very new to web languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code

```
<?php
  $nameErr = $teleErr = $emailErr = $partyErr = $vipErr = $reservationErr = $timeErr = "";
  $name = $tele = $email = $party = $vip = $reservation = $time = "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Please enter a full name";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Invalid name entered";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["tele"])) {
    $teleErr = "Please enter a telephone number";
  } else {
    $tele = test_input($_POST["tele"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]{7,}$/",$tele)) {
        $teleErr = "Invalid telephone number entered";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Please enter an email address";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email entered";
    }
  }

  if($_POST['party']=="") {
    $partyErr = "Please select the party size";
  } else {
    $party = test_input($_POST["party"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["vip"])) {
    $vipErr = "Please make a VIP area selection";
  } else {
    $vip = test_input($_POST["vip"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["reservation"])) {
    $reservationErr = "Please enter the reservation date";
  } else {
    $reservation = test_input($_POST["reservation"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/",$reservation)) {
        $reservationErr = "Invalid reservation date";
  }
 }

 if($_POST['time']=="") {
    $timeErr = "Please select the reservation time";
 } else {
    $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
 }

 if($nameErr == "" && $teleErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $partyErr == "" && $vipErr == "" &&  $reservationErr == "" && $timeErr == ""){

    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/dashboard');
    exit();

}

 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
 }
```

?>

Comment: This will bypass the validation I believe?

Comment: If you go thourgh the code you will find that it will always check for null value for all the variables you have created for storing error. And in php execution always happens from top to bottom not from bottom to top. So your all validation if will be executed first then it will go to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have applied your suggestions however all that happens is the reservations page is just redirected as soon as I click it, instead of letting the user fill out and validate the form first. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: you have to identify at your own by giving die one by one to each if of your validation check whether code goes their or not like if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Invalid name entered";die("name");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your user using the `header()`.

```
header('Location: http://yoursite.com/dashboard');
exit();
```

Comment: Where would I implement this? When I have tried to implement this before it just sends me straight to the confirmation page before the form is filled out. I think it is because my file structure is incorrect? Could you please show me a working example of how this can be implemented so I can get a better idea? :(

Answer (score 0):

Where are you sending this form data to?. To itself or database. Anyway upon submission, you can echo 
any of this javascript function to
redirect the user to a new page after 1 seconds.

```
echo "<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'redirect.php';
}, 1000);
</script>";


or


echo '<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.setInterval(function() {
    var timeLeft    = $("#timeLeft").html();                                
        if(eval(timeLeft) == 0){
                window.location= ("welcome.php");                 
        }else{              
            $("#timeLeft").html(eval(timeLeft)- eval(1));
        }
    }, 1000); 
});  
</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not currently using a database. I have a server which I have uploaded the page to and I wish for it to redirect after the form is filled out and validated. How would I implement your example into my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$nameErr = $teleErr = $emailErr = $partyErr = $vipErr = $reservationErr = $timeErr = "";
$name = $tele = $email = $party = $vip = $reservation = $time = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $c = 0;

    if(empty($_POST["name"])) { {
        $nameErr = "Please enter a full name";
        $c++;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Invalid name entered";
            $c++;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["tele"])) {
        $teleErr = "Please enter a telephone number";
        $c++;
    } 


    if (!empty($_POST["tele"])) {
        $tele = test_input($_POST["tele"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]{7,}$/",$tele)) {
            $teleErr = "Invalid telephone number entered";
            $c++;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Please enter an email address";
        $c++;
    } 

    if (!empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email entered";
            $c++;
        }
    }

    if($_POST['party']=="") {
        $partyErr = "Please select the party size";
        $c++;
    } else {
        $party = test_input($_POST["party"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["vip"])) {
        $vipErr = "Please make a VIP area selection";
        $c++;
    } else {
        $vip = test_input($_POST["vip"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["reservation"])) {
        $reservationErr = "Please enter the reservation date";
        $c++;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["reservation"])) {
        $reservation = test_input($_POST["reservation"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/",$reservation)) {
            $reservationErr = "Invalid reservation date";
            $c++;
        }
    }

    if($_POST['time']=="") {
        $timeErr = "Please select the reservation time";
        $c++;
    } else {
        $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
    }

    if($c == 0) {
        // redirect here
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what code should I put in the "redirect here" section of your example?

Comment: header('location: yoursite.com');

Comment: I implemented this however once I click submit on the form it just refreshes the form and doesnt direct me to a new page :( Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have done a lot of complication without using `Arrays`. You may in the case of an error existence set an array named `$errors` and its key should be the element of the form which is being on check. For example look at the following blue print code:

```
if (!my_check_email($_POST['email'])){
/* my_check_email() is a custom function the performs email validation. It returns true for valid email and it returns false for invalid email 
*/
// Here invalid email
$errors['email'] = true;
}
```

The repeat similar coding style for other elements of the form you want to validate.  At the end you just have to check if the `$errors` is set or not as follows:

if (isset($errors)){
// do the necessary code for invalid input
}
else{
// Save the data and redirect the user using any mean of redirection.
}

#### Means of redirection

1- using php `header` function as other answers stated. However, using header function should be used before any output in your file i.e before any `echo` or `print` or even any new line or html tags in your script file.

2- using cient-side javascript like the follwoing:

```
echo "<script>\n
    window.location.href = 'redirect.php';\n
</script>";
```

3- Using client-side meta tag:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.indiana.edu/~account/new-directory" />';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I am finding it difficult to understand what you mean as I am unexperienced with web code. Could you perhaps show me a working example so I can understand better? I really need to get this working :(

Comment: I looked at the link however this article doesnt concern php validation? Currently I have set it so the information is validated once the user clicks submit, I want the user to then be taken to a confirmation page if validation is passed. I know how to redirect using a form action method however I want to ensure that the fields are validated first. I hope this makes sense